# Why my computer port is still closed

Tags: windows-8.1, port-forwarding, port

I am trying to open a port. First, I tried to open the port in the Windows 8.1 Firewall Settings but didn't succeed. 
Then I disabled the Windows Firewall altogether. But, even after disabling it, my ports are closed (I tried 8-10 different ports). Then, I asked my ISP whether they are blocking any ports and they said no.
I have broadband with a dynamic IP.

Comment: your post needs to be at least 4 times the length, with lots of screenshots and descriptions about what you did and what you expect and why you want to open a port and what you clicked and so on

Comment: You also need to tell us if there is a router involved.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to connect from "outside" or from within your local network? If you try it from outside you mostly have to forward those ports within your router. Sometimes (depends on model) you can also set a ZMR host so all connections the router dont know where to send it, he will send it to that DMZ host.